# Dynamically change images based content of css class

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to automate a potentially lengthy process for a new site I am setting up. Basically, what I would like to do is post a thumbnail image on a page but have a javascript determine which image to post based on the content of a css class.

1) All of the images I would have would be pre-loaded onto the server in a directory named "logos"

2) The css class would be part of every page (in this instance the class name is "title")

3) Both the image name and css class content would be the same - so as an example, if someone lands on a client page where the css class "title" would contain the company name: "Company X" - there would be a corresponding company logo with the name "Company X.jpg"

I was trying to do this by coding an image placeholder on the page, then calling a javascript to change the "img src" of that placeholder based on it's id name "compLogo". I was using the javascript below:

```
var link = getElementsByClassName("title");
images = "<img src=/logos/'>"
document.getElementById("compLogo").innerHTML = 'images' + '[link]' + '.jpg';
```

However the script is not correctly writing the image source so the image is showing up broken on my page. I'm obviously very new to JS, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `where the css class "title" would contain the company name: "Company X"`? Please elaborate. In the className? in some text? Where?

Comment: The site is a wordpress theme I created - so I have a css class "title" that fills in with the page name automatically. Each page is named after a company - so when loading each page, the class "title" contains the company name (the class "fills" with the text of the company name).

Comment: That's weird. Spaces in your HTML class attribute would mean they are separate classes. Bad coding practice.

Comment: No classes contain spaces - the HTML content does (thus the name of the page). To bypass this, I can get the unique identifier by using the url (which in this case would be: "http://www.testsite.com/company-x/" but I was having trouble getting the url suffix and ingesting that into the img src

Comment: We need to know where "Company X" and the like show up in the HTML. Either that, or show us JavaScript pointing to the Element that contains "Company X"..

Comment: "Company X" shows up as the page title for the wordpress theme. The javascript I am using to try and get that title is in the sidebar.php file that is loaded for each wordpress page...

Comment: You really have to have a basic understanding of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and PHP to use Wordpress like you want. I suggest learning the basics.

Comment: Thank you, that helps out tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else needing help, I was able to figure out a solution.

```
var link = document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].textContent;
var imageurl = "<img src=\"http://testsite.com/logos/";
var suffix = ".jpg\">"
document.getElementById("compLogo").innerHTML = imageurl + link + suffix;
```

This works perfectly. If you create a div container in your html named: "compLogo" and place a link to this javascript, it will "grab" the image file that has the same name as the text content of your class name (in this instance "title") and place it accordingly. Use css to style your "compLogo" Id any way you want.

The reason my initial code was not working was due to not identifying the type of content I was trying to target in the node. By adding "[0].textContent" fixed that. I also mistakenly omitted the "document" prior to the "getElementsByClassName".

Alternately, if you want to target the last part of your url as your "source" name for your images (which is what I ended up using), use the following code:

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[2];
var imageurl = "<img src=\"http://testsite.com/logos/";
var suffix = ".jpg\">"
document.getElementById("compLogo").innerHTML = imageurl + secondLevelLocation + suffix;
```

(a thank you to css-tricks.com for the window.location code)

This way, if you use %post-name% permalinks in your wordpress site, the code above, will grab the the name of the post/page url. If you need to correlate an image with a post url, just name the image: 'your-post-url-name.jpg' and you're good to go.

I was honestly just searching for where I was going wrong PHPglue and you were no help at all. I clearly stated that I am new to JS... Next time, if you have nothing legitimate to offer, don't waste anyone's time.